# express cant find route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i have a node.js back-end with express sever.

i have routes called  templete.rpoutes.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const templateCtrl = require("../controllers/template.controller");

const router = express.Router();

router.route("/createtemplate").post(templateCtrl.createTemplate);
router.route("/uploadFinalTemplate").post(templateCtrl.uploadFinalTemplate);

// beneath are the routes with issue
router.route("/:templateId/productInfos").get(templateCtrl.productInfos);
router.route("/:templateId").get(templateCtrl.Read);

// router.param("templateId", templateCtrl.templateByID);

module.exports = router;
```

I have  the  defined  method  in template controller  where  i'm just  logging  stuff. no backend logic  is there  yet. so I expect  when I make  a  call to these  end point, i should  get those logs displayed

I have configured  express  server as:

```
app.use("/api/template", templateRoute);
app.use("/api/productInfo", productInfoRoute);
app.use('/api/sendInformation', Notify)

// PORT
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Connected to port " + port);
});
```

Note: the app is express.router() method and the controllers are required correctly and the other end-points work for the same controller.

so when I send a get request from postman to `localhost:5000/api/template/5f870cd3b02fd77d0a576a54` I get  a 404 and Not found in my console  like this: (Plus  the  server is  running)[image]

Comment: try replacing `router.route("/createtemplate").` with `router.post('/createtemplate', templateCtrl.createTemplate)` and same for others

Answer (score 0):

as described in the documentation https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router

```
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/createtemplate",templateCtrl.createTemplate);
router.post("/uploadFinalTemplate",templateCtrl.uploadFinalTemplate);

router.get("/:templateId/productInfos",templateCtrl.productInfos);
router.get("/:templateId",templateCtrl.Read);
```